# How do I know if I.m getting 4000 lb. concrete as quoted, vs. 3000 or 3500 lb

Tags: concrete

how do I know if I'm getting 4000 lb. concrete, as quoted, and not something less strong? Also, is there a significant difference in strength, for a garage floor, between 3000, 3500, and 4000 lb. concrete?

Comment: What are you planning to do in the garage that requires a high strength pad ?

Comment: There are many ways, try this link, it gives you several ASTM tests. https://www.concretenetwork.com/concrete-testing/

Comment: @blacksmith37 See: http://www.buildingcode.online/1232.html ***or*** 1904.2d: https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IBC2012/chapter-19-concrete

Comment: Assuming the concrete is yet to arrive as you ask this question, the most bang for the buck you'll get in slab strength is properly placed reinforcing steel, (or more of it) which is comparatively inexpensive and makes a huge difference in slab performance, but often neglected entirely or under-done.

Answer (score 7):

If you don’t want to go to the time and expense of having cylinders taken and tested, you can do some homework yourself.

Ask for the “Batch Ticket” from the concrete truck driver when he arrives at the site before he unloads. The ticket will show the “order” that was called in and required… 3000, 4000, etc.  Then look to see when the batch was made. They have about 90 minutes or so to get it made and delivered, depending on weather, strength, etc. (You can look this up on the internet.) If it exceeds this time limit, the concrete looses its strength… for several reasons and should not be used.

The batch ticket will show amount of different types of materials used in the mix design. You can check these quantities on the internet to see what the mix equals… 3000, 4000, etc. (I’d check with ACI Standards, they are the gold standard.)

Now, all that can be perfect, but if they add a bunch of water to the mix in the drum when they arrive, it will weaken the mix. They will add water because it’s a slab pour and they all like it wet because it’s easier to “work” and trowel to a nice finish. I’d ask the truck driver how much water he’s adding and then check on the internet to see if the quantity is acceptable according to ACI Standards.

Remember, taking tests is the only sure way of knowing, but this will work for non critical structural designs. Oh, also, stick around there could be 2-3 trucks to check and they’ll arrive at different times.

Comment: I don't know what the test is called (and maybe you know): I have seen an independent testing company on site testing the wet concrete and signing off on the strength. They checked the batch ticket, like you mention, and then put the wet sludge in a sealable bucket sized container, then (I think) pulled out the air and (I think) weighed it to determine the water content. I looked it up but found microwave/sieve type on-site tests but nothing with this vacuum/pressurized bucket. Lee, do you know what it might have been?

Comment: @P2000. I think you’re thinking of a “slump test”.

Comment: I don't recall he emptied the container to observe the slump. More like he measured something (weight?) after pressurizing the container or driving water out maybe... unless that's also called a slump test of course.

Comment: He filled a cone with concrete and then lifted the cone out of the way. Then he measured how far the concrete sunk down without the cone holding it in place. The difference is the slump test result…. Usually about 4” is a good result.

Comment: Slump has nothing to do with the amount of Portland cement in the mix but the amount of water. If a batch ticket was all telling it would work for commercial tests but no it takes a certified compression test this is the only way to know absolutely.

Comment: Found it: "Air Content Test" for entrained concrete. He also did the slump test.

Answer (score 3):

Get some compression tubes and pull a tube at the start and close to the end of the pour. After it is cured have it tested (they crush it) and you know what the strength is of the slab. I haven’t had to do this on slabs but mono pours that also include the foundation I have had to do in the past.

Comment: Did this all the time for footing for substation transformers.  There are companies that will test on site, but they're expensive.+1

Comment: Compression tubes only work if you know how to load them and properly store them until tested. (You fill them 1/3 at a time and “rod” the concrete 25 times at each lift… otherwise it’s useless and the contractor will probably disregard any complaints.